# Obtain transfer function from signal flow graph

Tags: matlab, filters, filter-design, continuous-signals, transfer-function

I have a pretty complex signal flow graph with all the blocks and the branches completely describing an analog filter, in the Laplace complex variable s. The signal $X(s)$ is the input and $Y(s)$ is the output.

Is there any (free) tool which can analyze such a graph and provide the overall transfer function $H(s) = Y(s)/X(s)$?

Googling I found [this](http://www.ni.com/labview/mathscript/) Matlab tool, but the tool it is not free; anyway is there anything similar, in Matlab or in other environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that for complex systems finding such free standalone tool would be hard. Obviously since you mentioned MATLAB, you should use Simulink then or this tool:

[**Fully Automated Flowgraph Analysis Tool**](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7224-a-fully-automated-flowgraph-analysis-tool-for-matlab). Manual to be found [**here**](http://read.pudn.com/downloads141/sourcecode/others/607984/flowg_tool/manual.pdf).

Alternatively you might look into this [**Mason.m**](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22-mason-m) tool. Or this [**masonry**](https://github.com/saschpe/masonry) tool.

I know that [**these guys**](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0906/0906.5561.pdf) also did similar work once.